# Text file to csv with glob. Need to change delimiter depending on section of file being read

Tags: python, parsing, csv, text, glob

I have a text file that doesn't have a standard delimiter. I need to be able to check if the current line is equal to a certain phrase and if it is, the code should use a certain delimiter until another phrase is found. delimiters used are  '**,**' '**-**','**:**' and '**=**'.

Please help me out :)

This is what my code is at the moment

```
import csv
import glob
import os

directory = raw_input("INPUT Folder for Log Dump Files:")
output = raw_input("OUTPUT Folder for .csv files:")

txt_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')

for txt_file in glob.glob(txt_files):
    with open(txt_file, "rb") as input_file:
        in_txt = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=':')
        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(txt_file))[0] + '.csv'

    with open(os.path.join(output, filename), 'wb') as output_file:
        out_csv = csv.writer(output_file)
        out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

Comment: What is the phrase and what delimiters do you want the output file to have in it?

Comment: Do you have an example of the CSV file?

Comment: The phrase would change for each section in the file.I'm going to have to have multiple rules. Each seperate for each phrase. I'll be using the phrase bit to search for the title of each section. The text is mostly formatted like a table. Without table lines. Its a drive log dump file.

Comment: I can't provide the file unfortunately ,sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot speak to the time efficiency of this method, but it might just get what you want done. The basic idea is to create a list to contain the lines of each text file, and then output the list to your new csv file. You save a 'delimiter' variable and then change it by checking each line as you go through the text files.

For example:
I created two text files on my Desktop. They read as follows:

delimiter_test_1.txt

> test=delimiter=here
>
> does-it-work
>
> I'm:Not:Sure

delimiter_test_2.txt

> This:File:Uses:Colons
>
> Pretty:Much:The:Whole:Time
>
> does-it-work
>
> If-Written-Correctly-yes

I then ran this script on them:

```
import csv
import glob
import os

directory = raw_input("INPUT Folder for Log Dump Files:")
output = raw_input("OUTPUT Folder for .csv files:")

txt_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')

delimiter = ':'
for txt_file in glob.glob(txt_files):
    SavingList = []

    with open(txt_file, 'r') as text:
            for line in text:
                if line == 'test=delimiter=here\n':
                    delimiter = '='
                elif line == 'does-it-work\n':
                    delimiter = '-'
                elif line == "I'm:Not:Sure":
                    delimiter = ':'
        
                SavingList.append(line.split(delimiter))

    with open('%s.csv' %os.path.join(output, txt_file.split('.')[0]), 'wb') as output_file:
            writer = csv.writer(output_file)
            for m in xrange(len(SavingList)):
                writer.writerow(SavingList[m])
```

And got two csv files with the text split based on the desired delimiter. Depending on how many different lines you have for changing the delimiter you could set up a dictionary of said lines. Then your check becomes:

```
if line in my_dictionary.keys():
    delimiter = my_dictionary[line]
```

for example.

Comment: Great. That looks like exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll try it now and let you know how it goes. Thank you!!  Do you think there is  a more efficient /better method for me to do this though ?

Comment: There may well be one, but if there is, I'm not going to be the person to find it. My talent lies in hacking together inelegant solutions. I use the csv module a lot to trim CSVs from millions of lines of data I don't care about to a few thousand I do. As it's personal use and not part of a package I have to deliver to others, I've not much interest in elegance.